# How to raise an exception in Python 3.3

Tags: python, exception, python-3.3

I am currently reading tutorials in tutorialspoint's python tutorials. But it's the tutorial of Python 2 not Python 3.3 which I have right now. Well, I managed to search in the internet and found out about some changes. But this one is pretty tough.

So, in tutorialspoint the python source code for raising an exception is:

```
def functionName( level ):
if level < 1:
   raise "Invalid level!", level
  # The code below to this would not be executed
  # if we raise the exception
```

But if I type

```
raise "Invalid level!", level
```

it says syntax error. 
So, I want to know how I raise an exception in Python 3.3.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
raise Exception("Invalid level! " + level)
```

I would really recommend you to read the [Python docs.](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an Exception object:

```
 raise Exception('spam', 'eggs')
```

See the docs here:
http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

Comment: Oh, yes. But I can't accept it right now.. I have to wait few more minutes before I can do that.

Comment: But I don't know which one to choose, sorry. I have no idea which answer is more relevant to me. Both have helped me.

Comment: @James, Doesn't matter too much :) Just pick one so that the question can be marked as closed

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here is a simple example:

```
# Raise exception if x != 4
try:
    x = 3
    if (x != 4):
        raise Exception('X is not 4')
except Exception as e:
    print('ERROR: ', e)
```

Comment: What does this add to the existing answers?

Comment: It's simply a working, rudimentary usage of "try-catch" in python for complete beginners. A copy-paste code block for quick reference if you will. The other answers only include the raise statement.

Comment: Which is all the OP asked about.